# is it possible to utilize two $stmt mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hello I have a question when I use my `$stmt` to execute an insert query into my database it works perfectly fine, however when I use a `$stmt2` after that execute to UPDATE a different table it won't update the table even though to my understanding the code is correct.

The code I have tried to fix many times is as so

```
$mysqli= my database connection
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `test_table`(datenow,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7,test8, 
test9,test10,test11,test12,test14,test15,test16,test17,test18,) 
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)") 
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssss',$test1,$test2,$test3,$test4,$test5,$test6,$test7,$test8,$test9,$test10,$test11,$test12,$test13,$test14, $test15,$test16,$test17,$test18);
$stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET productID='1', purchase_date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, end_date=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) WHERE username = ?");
$stmt1->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt1->execute();
$stmt->execute();
```

Any help would be very appreciated thanks!

Comment: Why do you use `$mysqli` for `$stmt` and `$link` for `$stmt1`? Do you have two database connections?

Comment: $link is the same as $mysqli because I thought after a execute it would close the connection I changed the coding on my debugging to $mysqli instead of $link but $stmt1 still doesnt work, I am using the same database but trying to connect to 2 different tables to alter what is in them

Comment: You have an extra comma after `test18` in the first query. Is that in your real code?

Answer (score 0):

A prepared statement can only execute one MySQL query. You can prepare as many statements as you want in different variables

so you can change it as:

```
$stmt1 = $link->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET productID='1', purchase_date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, end_date=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) WHERE username = ?");
$stmt1->bind_param('s', $username);
```

to

```
$stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET productID='1', purchase_date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, end_date=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) WHERE username = ?");
$stmt1->bind_param('s', $username);
```

see no need of $link, you can prepare many statement for different variable...Thanks

Comment: How does it answer his question?